# Repeated crashes using a Boolean / Difference Modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]I am trying to model a pistol in blender, when i try to subtract the solid block using the boolean tool all it does is crash my program. Any help solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Pistol Model Boolean]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If Blender is crashing repeatably, it sounds like a bug; see [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1377/1253) for information about reporting them.

Comment: Also, it would be most helpful if you would post at least a screenshot of your modifier panel or perhaps your .blend file, since not much can be assumed from your screenshot.

Comment: It did not crash for me (with 2.74); however, I did notice some other problems that might be helpful to know about. `Hammer_cut` had an unused Boolean modifier applied to it, which was causing the Boolean modifier on `Stock` to fail. The `Stock` mesh had several non-manifold areas, which you can select with Ctrl + Alt + Shift + M, although I think none of them affect the problem area.